# Tkinter "on-pack" method or "is-packed" attribute

Tags: python, macos, oop, tkinter

I'm making a GUI with Tkinter, and I need to find a way to know if a widget (let's call it `l = Label(root, text="test")`) is packed or not. I know I can do `if l in Tk.pack_slaves(root):...`, but this seems inefficient.

Is there any way of adding a "line" to the `widget.pack()` method, such as telling it to set an attribute to `widget.is_packed = True`? Or is there a way of telling a class, `On_method_call(pack())` do this?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you want to know if you've called pack, or do you just want to know if a widget is visible? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to know when pack is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to do it. It's your code doing the packing, so you can store a flag in a dictionary, or create your own pack function to do that automatically.